# How to style two different ways in one string in QT Framework

Tags: c++, css, qt

Here's a code snippet:

```
QLabel *lbl = new QLabel("Current Value : <span>100 V</span>");    
lbl->setStyleSheet("color:#000000; font-size:14px;");    
lbl->setStyleSheet("QLabel span { font-size:18px; }");
```

How to use two different styles in one string in Qt?
I tried but it does not work.

Is there any method to do this type of style?
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23490017/how-to-add-style-via-setstylesheet-without-losing-orignal-style-in-qt


something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As each HTML tag can have its own `style` attribute so you can do something like this in `span`:

```
QLabel *lbl = new QLabel( "Current Value : <span style='font-size:18px;'>100 V</span>" );

lbl->setStyleSheet( "color:#000000; font-size:14px;" );
```

Here's a snapshot:
[image]

Comment: This is QT Framework, here this type of inline style in span is not allowed.. This way is not working.

Comment: @SenthilKumar: I've posted my answer after testing it first. I've updated it with a snapshot of the output. BTW, you can customize Qt Widgets that are quite comfortable rendering `HTML`. Here's the [Qt Style Sheets Reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) if you are interested to learn more.

Comment: Thank Azeem, Its working i tried.. Previously i tried in setStylesheet i used span not working. But now using setText i used.. Now working.. Thanks for effort..

Comment: @SenthilKumar: My pleasure! :) I'm glad I could help.