# Qt: Change font depending on status :enabled :disabled CSS

Tags: css, qt, font-size

I have different QLabels with the following stylesheet. Surprisingly, when they are disabled, the color changes, but not the font-size nor the font-weight. The font is always the one defined in QLabel (regardless of wether the label is enabled or not). Is there anything I missed?

```
setStyleSheet(QString(
            "QLabel{"
            "    font-family: %1; "
            "    font-size: 16px; "
            "    font-weight: bold; "
            "    color: %3; "
            "}"
            "QLabel::!enabled {"
            "    font-size: 12px; "
            "    font-weight: normal; "
            "    color: %2; "
            "}").arg(fontFamilyName).arg(MEDIUM_GREY).arg(SUPER_DARK_GREY));
```

Comment: Consider this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23490017/how-to-add-style-via-setstylesheet-without-losing-orignal-style-in-qt?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 0):

I would start by changing `QLabel::!enabled` with `QLabel:disabled`. Enabled and disabled are **pseudo-states** and according to the documentation [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) they are accessed with a single colon, not a double one.

Apart from that, you may still experience some Qt Style Sheets bugs (can't be sure since you didn't mention the Qt version you are using).

If after changing the `!enabled` to `:disabled` the problem is still present, I would suggest to try these workarounds:

Two workarounds which *may* work are:

1. Set the font family in the *!enabled* part too, although it seems redundant;
2. Set a background (e.g. `background-color: transparent`;

For more details about the possible Qt Style Sheet bugs you may face, I would suggest to have a look at the Qt bug tracker [here](http://bugreports.qt.io).

Comment: Yep... just tested with Qt 5.10.1... I think it's a indeed a Qt bug. You may file a bug report and see if they come with more suggestions.